# Create a Attribute programmatically, Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I just started wit Core Data. I wanna create a Attribute programmatically. When the user press the add button, two new Attribute (string) should be created called "firstName" and "lastName". How would I do that?

Comment: You *cannot* programmatically add attributes to a Core Data entity after the model has been assigned to a managed object context. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536502/programmatically-create-attribute-core-data.

Comment: So there is no way to to that?

Comment: No. You can create a managed object model in Xcode or programmatically. But once it is created and used, you cannot change it.